# Why every time I make a rebase all the files on my branch are deleted (except the conflicting ones)?

Tags: git, rebase

**base-branch** changes

- file1 - changed
- file2 - unchanged

**my-branch** (forked from base-branch)

- file1 - changed
- file2 - removed
- file3 - added
- file4 - added

while on my branch, I run: `git rebase base-branch`

Excepted result:

- file1: conflict
- file2: removed
- file3: added
- file4: added

Actual result:

- file1: conflict (and it's not even showed clearly by any git diff tool as if the "git conflict markers" were misplaced, or ignored)
- file2: added
- file3: removed
- file4: removed

**Why?** (with `git merge base-branch -no-ff` it works perfectly)

Is it possible it should be the other way around? e.g. first merge the latest `base-branch` into `my-branch`, then **rebase** `my-branch` into `base-branch`?

Comment: Without seeing the actual commits involved, it's very hard to say. Is this repository available for public consumption?

Comment: @torek it's a private repository but the explanation reflects exactly what's happening. it's not a single merge... it happens every time

Comment: When files disappear, check the output of `git status`. Rebase may be still in progress.

Comment: You need to remember that rebase works by *copying* commits, one at a time, then switching from the originals (pre-rebase) to the new (and presumably improved) post-rebase ones. Merge *does not* copy commits, it just adds a new merge commit. So if you have several commits, some of which add files, you'll see files disappear and then reappear as the rebase progresses. You can get conflicts on *each* copied commit.

Comment: Again, if we had access to the repository in question—or if you made a similar repository with an example that shows the same issues—I could explain in detail, but with a simple claim like that in your question, all I can say is that this is entirely normal in some cases, and you have presumably hit one of those cases.

Comment: At what step of rebasing are you seeing that result?  If it's at the conflict level it's normal since the last of the changes hasn't been applied yet.  When you fix the conflict and `rebase --continue`  you should see the rest.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and sorry for the delay in the answer! I think this is what happened: branch A (commit A-B) was worked to branch B (commit B-C-D). then branch B was merged into branch A.
Later, I kept working on branch B, and when rebased A into B the OLD version of my branch was overridden on top of the current branch (NEW version with more commits of branch B). makes any sense? I wonder if by any chance `rebase -i` would help (i.e. excluding from the rebase the commits originally coming from branch B)

Comment: At answering to "at what step": at the end. I could confirm no ongoing rebase with `git status`

Answer (score 0):

I did some more rebases following the proper flow ( main branch('A') -> new branch('B') -> rebase latest changes on new branch which are not in new branch) and it worked fine.

So, looks like the issue with **changes being overridden** was the following:

1. branch A (commit A-B) was forked to branch B (commit B-C-D)
2. then branch B was merged into branch A.
3. Later, I kept working on branch B (including making changes or deleting on files merged in 2) )
4. when rebased A into B (`checkout B -> rebase A;`) the OLD version of the files changed both in branch A and B was used on top of the current branch

It seems with a `rebase -i` , excluding common changes ( **2)** ) the problem should not happen